# Terraform Destroy does not work with Azure Devops Variables in terraform.tfvars

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have very simple pipeline, classic pipeline with Terraform Init, Plan and Apply, how ever deployment failed in middle, so I wanted to destroy all resources…
(backend is remote sitting on Azure blob container
so I enabled only Init and Destroy Task in pipeline, In Init parameters I have provided remote backend details, but when I run pipeline with destroy command it says " variable not allowed"

Actually in terraform.tfvars file I have used azure variable group variable substitution like below

[image]

and I have destory task like below

[image]

error i get is:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code nor erros as screenshots, but use properly formatted code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

"It isn’t possible to define anything other than static values in a .tfvars file.", see [Reference environment variables in .tfvars file](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/reference-environment-variables-in-tfvars-file/35475/2).

Alternativly, you can rename the environment variables to start with `TF_VAR_` prefix, e.g. `TF_VAR_resource_group` or you can try to pass the values via `-var` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion,  what I did after more research is , I didnt declare any values in tfvars. instead converted this tfvars into json format and then used FileTransform Task which populated values to this tfvars.json file, at this point I can see this file has all values populated and will test further.

Answer (score 0):

I normally recommend against this type of solutions as it's non-canonical; e.g. there are ways to solve the problem, as @sschmeck has posted, so adding a third-party tool can just create more of a headache.

That said, [this article](https://dev.to/pwd9000/dynamic-terraform-deployments-using-devops-replace-tokens-5aeb#:%7E:text=Installing%20Replace%20Tokens&text=Go%20to%20DevOps%20Organisation%20Settings,tasks%20in%20our%20DevOps%20pipeline.) details the use a "Replace Tokens" task in Azure DevOps.

Simply put, you can tell this task to scan for `*.tfvars` files, and have it replace some tokens with a pattern such as `__example__`, so in your example:

```
resource_group = __resource_group__
```

And set the `resource_group` variable in a Azure DevOps variable group; it will then search for your specified pattern and replace it.

Again, I would say use `TF_VAR`s as it's canonical, but this may also work for you.